# The "NASA's Eyes" virtual broadcasting of Perseverance's Mars arrival

Tags: perseverance

Will the "NASA's Eyes" site [show](https://eyes.nasa.gov/apps/orrery/#/sc_perseverance) (virually, of course) Cruise Stage separation and atmospheric braking of "Perseverance" in real time?

Can I rewind the "NASA's Eyes" "recording" to rewatch it later?

Comment: Maybe this scheduled broadcast event will show those details? You probably know already! The video will be available to rewind after the live broadasting https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gm0b_ijaYMQ

Comment: The exiting part is not this. It will be when China announces they have found life, and NASA (after knowing about it for 5 decades) will say their tests are not sufficient. Perhaps NASA will already announce that they "believe" they have found life but want to verify through SRM. Either way this will be a fun year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a time acceleration bar in the NASA Eyes orrery by quadruple clicking on the time. When you move forward to the time of landing, it doesn't show any stage separation and instead just shows the spacecraft moving inside of Mars.

But this page will show a visualization: https://eyes.nasa.gov/apps/mars2020/#/home

> On the day of the event itself, the timeline may be slightly different, but this represents the expected set of events using the best available engineering data. [...]
>
> Once the Perseverance rover lands on Mars, you can click the “Replay” button to start again at the beginning. If you are watching it live on February 18th, 2021, a button will say "LIVE” [...]

Also you might rather just watch the official YouTube livestream: